# How can I operate with previous results (Python)

Tags: python

I am new in python and i need some advice.

The thing is that i dont know how to calculate something with previuos results.
In order to explain in a better way i will provide u an example:
I want to calculate the arithmetical mean of 5 numbers so:

A + B + C + D + E (First of all i add them)
Then i have to divide bteween 5 but i dont want to put this again  (A + B + C + D + E).
The thing which i am asking is how can i express the first operation with a word or something.

Comment: With a word? What do you mean with a word?

Comment: do something like `sum = A+B+C+D+E`. Then you can use "sum" in the future and do something like `result = sum / 5`

Comment: Thanks for the efforts i already manage to solve that little problem. Thanks again.

Comment: zinki thanks a lot for making it clear to me

Answer (score 1):

Save the first result as a variable, then reference that variable by name later.

```
x = A + B + C + D + E
print(x/5)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python Idle, you can use `_` to access the previous result:

```
>>> 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5
15
>>> # Here _ = 15
>>> _ // 5
3
>>>
```